# good methods for boolean operations on overlapping polygons

Tags: gis, shapefile

What is the best open source library for performing boolean operations (union, intersect, subtract) on vector geometry (polygons and polylines), such as the type stored in shapefiles? What do you like to use?

OGR looks like it probably has this capability, though I'm having trouble finding the particular commands in their documentation.
Shapely definitely does this, and is easy to understand.
PostGIS appears to also have some commands for this.

But there must be more, and I'm having trouble finding them.

I don't have much experience with any of the above libraries, and would appreciate any opinions on these or other libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: PostGis (spatial extensions for the PostgreSql DB), GDAL/OGR - reading and writing of vector and raster formats, GEOS (Shapely is just a wrapper over GEOS iirc, there used to be python OGR /GDAL wrappers around) are all *very fine* open-source libraries for geospatial work (I can recommend all of these fully). BTW: PostgreSQL also uses GEOS & GDAL & Proj4 etc. In geospatial open-source you'll see a lot of libraries used in many places (e.g. Mapserver, Geoserver, ...)

Comment: Also: a good place to ask this type of question is gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I don't think OGR can help you do this, though it sort of could if your data were in a spatial database that supported these operations via SQL - you could pass in the geomety-manipulating query and OGR would receive the result from the DB in the usual way.

Check out the GEOS library, I'm pretty sure it could do this, but I've not used it so I can't answer further  http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/

Answer (score 1):

Just a little correction: Shapely doesn't operate on shapefiles, it operates on single or multipart geometric objects. In conjunction with a shapefile reader/writer it *could be used* in a program that does binary operations file-wise (for example, I have a service that spatially compares GeoRSS feeds at http://sgillies.net/mush.html), but like you, I haven't seen that type of thing outside of proprietary software like ArcMap.

Comment: thanks, correction noted and made. and thanks for Shapely! any recommendations on shapefile reader/writers to use with shapely? I started making a shapefile reader(github.com/bengolder/pyshapefile), but haven't yet made it shapely friendly, and someone's probably made a better one already.  That georss service is really neat.